# Why is IsCancellationRequested not set to true on stopping a BackgroundService in .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, .net-core, cancellation-token, application-lifecycle

I've read most articles I can find about [IHostApplicationLifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1#ihostapplicationlifetime-1) and CancellationToken's in .NET Core 3.1, but I cannot find a reason why this is not working.

I have a simple [BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#backgroundservice-base-class) which look like the following:

```
    public class AnotherWorker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _hostApplicationLifetime;

        public AnotherWorker(IHostApplicationLifetime hostApplicationLifetime)
        {
            _hostApplicationLifetime = hostApplicationLifetime;
        }

        public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Process id: {Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id}");
            _hostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() => Console.WriteLine("Started"));
            _hostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() => Console.WriteLine("Stopping"));
            _hostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() => Console.WriteLine("Stopped"));

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Executing");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
        // This actually prints "Stop. IsCancellationRequested: False". Why?
            Console.WriteLine($"Stop. IsCancellationRequested: {cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested}");
            await base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

The ConsoleLifetime is added by default, which listens to Ctrl+C and SIGTERM and informs the IHostApplicationLifetime. I guess IHostApplicationLifetime in turn should then cancel all CancellationTokens? [Here's a good article on the subject](https://andrewlock.net/introducing-ihostlifetime-and-untangling-the-generic-host-startup-interactions/). So *why* is the output from the above code snippet the following?

```
Hosting starting
Started
Hosting started
(sends SIGTERM with `kill -s TERM <process_id>`)
Applicationis shuting down...
Stop. IsCancellationRequested: False
Stopped
Hosting stopped
```

I would expect it to log `Stop. IsCancellationRequested: True`

I want to be able to pass this token around, to other service calls, for them to have the capability to shutdown gracefully.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostinghostbuilderextensions.runconsoleasync?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: I don't think it is the same the `IsCancellationRequested` from the same token. For shutting down gracefully you need to do that on the `ExecuteAsync`. When you've a long runnning task there and checking the `IsCancellationRequested` there it will be true.
`CloseAsync` is just for cleaning up some data there not for gracefully shutdown. The token passed into `ExecuteAsync`is not the same as `CloseAsync`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There are a lot of different cancellation tokens here, and several different abstractions (`IHostApplicationLifetime`, `IHostedService`, `BackgroundService`). It takes a while to untangle everything. The blog post you linked to is fantastic, but doesn't go into detail on the `CancellationToken`s.

First, if you're going to use `BackgroundService`, I recommend [reading the code](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/release/3.1/src/Hosting/Abstractions/src/BackgroundService.cs). Also, I strongly recommend not overriding `StartAsync` and `StopAsync`; `BackgroundService` uses these in a very particular way.

[`IHostedService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostedservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) has two methods. `StartAsync` starts the service running (possibly asynchronously); it takes a `CancellationToken` that indicates the "start" operation should be cancelled (I haven't checked, but I assume this token is only triggered if the app is shutdown almost immediately). Note that `StartAsync` needs to *complete* before the hosted service is considered in the "started" or "running" state. Similarly, `StopAsync` stops the service (possibly asynchronously). `StopAsync` is invoked when the application begins its graceful shutdown. There's a timeout for the graceful shutdown period, after which the application begins its "I'm serious now" shutdown. The [`CancellationToken` for `StopAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostedservice.stopasync?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_Hosting_IHostedService_StopAsync_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) represents the transition from "graceful" to "I'm serious now". So it's *not* set during that graceful shutdown timeout window.

If you use `BackgroundService` instead of `IHostedService` directly (like most people do), you get a *different* `CancellationToken` in `ExecuteAsync`. This one [is set](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/release/3.1/src/Hosting/Abstractions/src/BackgroundService.cs#L59) when `BackgroundService.StopAsync` is invoked - i.e., when the application has started its graceful shutdown. So it's roughly equivalent to [`IHostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostapplicationlifetime.applicationstopping?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_Hosting_IHostApplicationLifetime_ApplicationStopping), but scoped to a single hosted service. You can expect the `BackgroundWorker.ExecuteAsync` `CancellationToken` to be set shortly after `IHostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping` is set.

Note that all of these `CancellationToken`s represent something different:

- `IHostedService.StartAsync`'s `CancellationToken` means "abort the starting of this service".
- `IHostedService.StopAsync`'s `CancellationToken` means "stop this service *right now*; you're out of the grace period".
- `IHostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping` means "the graceful shutdown sequence for this entire application has started; everyone please stop what you are doing".

  - As part of the graceful shutdown sequence, all `IHostedService.StopAsync` methods are invoked.
- `BackgroundService.ExecuteAsync`'s `CancellationToken` means "stop this service".

An interesting note is that `BackgroundService` types don't normally see the "I'm serious now" signal; they only see the "stop this service" signal. This is likely because the "I'm serious now" signal represented by a `CancellationToken` is somewhat confusing.

If you look into [the code for `Host`](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/release/3.1/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/Internal/Host.cs#L59), the shutdown sequence has *even more* cancellation tokens used in its shutdown sequence:

1. `IHost.StopAsync` takes a `CancellationToken` [meaning "the stop should no longer be graceful"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihost.stopasync?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1).
2. It then [starts a `CancellationToken`-based timeout for the graceful timeout period](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/release/3.1/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/Internal/Host.cs#L63).
3. ... and [another linked `CancellationToken`](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/release/3.1/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/Internal/Host.cs#L66) that is fired if *either* the `IHost.StopAsync` token is fired or if the timer elapsed. So this one also means "the stop should no longer be graceful".
4. Next it [calls `IHostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication`](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/release/3.1/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/Internal/Host.cs#L68), which [cancels the `IHostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping` `CancellationToken`](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/release/3.1/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/Internal/ApplicationLifetime.cs#L58).
5. It then [invokes `StopAsync` for each `IHostedService`](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/release/3.1/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/Internal/Host.cs#L78), passing the "stop should no longer be graceful" token.

   - All `BackgroundService` types have their own `CancellationToken` (which was passed to `ExecuteAsync` during startup), and those cancellation tokens are [cancelled by `StopAsync`](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/release/3.1/src/Hosting/Abstractions/src/BackgroundService.cs#L60).
6. Finally, it [invokes `IHostApplicationLifetime.NotifyStopped`](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/release/3.1/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/Internal/Host.cs#L91), which [cancels the `IHostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopped` `CancellationToken`](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/release/3.1/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/Internal/ApplicationLifetime.cs#L93).

I count 3 for the "no longer graceful" signal (one passed in, one timer, and one linking those two), plus 2 on `IHostApplicationLifetime`, plus 1 for each `BackgroundService`, for a total of `5 + n` cancellation tokens used during shutdown. :)

Comment: Now when you say it, it all feels more reasonable. Indeed there's a lot going on here. It's a bit unfortunate that the use of the same `CancellationToken` type everywhere makes the code a bit non self-explanatory. You'll have to treat them as very *context-specific* tokens, then it becomes a bit easier to reason about. Thanks Stephen!

Comment: So if I had a client of some sort that I would like to close the connection to, let's say a service bus subscription client. This API is asynchronous and i'd like to await it, however i'm not sure exactly *where* to call `await _subscriptionClient.CloseAsync` (without overriding the `StopAsync` method that is). IHostApplicationLifetime doesn't support asynchronous operations as far as I can tell, and I can't use the `CancellationToken` passed to `ExecuteAsync` either (because `token.Register` is neither asynchroous). Do you have any ideas here? Thanks.

Comment: If you're using `BackgroundService`, I'd just call `CloseAsync` in a `finally` branch just before the code exits `ExecuteAsync`. Bonus points: use `IAsyncDisposable`. :)

Comment: The problem is that the code I have in `ExecuteAsync` is not itself asynchronous, but rather a synchronous call that just instantiates a subscription client and wires up a message handler. Also, I don't think I can use `IAsyncDisposable` here since I want to "gracefully" call `CloseAsync` to stop the subscription client from receiving further messages long before `DisposeAsync` would even be called. Update: I guess my real problem here is that the subscription client doesn't seem to support cancellation token, so there is no way for me to pass the token from `ExecuteAsync` further down.

Comment: Right; it sounds like a client API issue. If it would be proper to call `CloseAsync` from a different thread than the one doing the synchronous `Receive`, then you could `Register` that up (with an `async void` lambda or sync-over-async hack) to the `CancellationToken` passed into `ExecuteAsync`. It wouldn't be pretty, but since the client doesn't support cancellation *and* requires an asynchronous teardown (an odd combo), you won't end up with a pretty solution anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The `CancellationToken` passed to the `StopAsync` indicate if the `BackgroundService` must execute a gracefull shutdown or a hard one.

You stop the process using the `kill -s TERM` so it send the `SIGTERM` signal asking the application to shutdown gracefully. Therefore the `IsCancellationRequested` property is still at false.

To pass a token to other services calls, you have to provide your own `CancellationToken`. You can use a `CancellationTokenSource` to manage token creation and cancellation.