# Worker Service's ExecuteAsync doesn't stop gracefully

Tags: .net-core, systemd, .net-7.0

I'm developing a worker-service application using .net7, and I'm able to run it as a unit on systemd.

I wish to have the application execute some code to gracefully shutdown, whenever a 'systemctl stop my.service' is issued, however it seems like it immediately shuts down

Program.cs:

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IConfiguration config)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _config = config;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {


        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("{env} - Worker running at: {time}",_config["env"], DateTimeOffset.Now);
            await Task.Delay(5000, stoppingToken);
        }

        _logger.LogInformation("this line is never executed after stop");
    }

    public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {

        await base.StopAsync(stoppingToken);

        _logger.LogInformation("this line is actually executed after stop");
    }
}
```

Both the output from inside the loop and the StopAsync are being printed successfully during run time and stop, I use  the following to access it:

`journalctl --unit=my.service -n 50 --no-pager`

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61094552/why-is-iscancellationrequested-not-set-to-true-on-stopping-a-backgroundservice-i , haven't skimmed that answer though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Both the output from inside the loop and the StopAsync are being printed successfully during run time and stop

Right, so it is exiting gracefully. The `base.StopAsync` is cancelling the token passed to `ExecuteAsync`. This almost always causes `Task.Delay` to throw an `OperationCanceledException`, causing the `ExecuteAsync` to complete.

If you want code in `ExecuteAsync` to always try to run during shutdown, put it in a `finally` block.